# Control wrap 100 images within a Grid

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get touch pointer inside a specific Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756523/how-to-get-touch-pointer-inside-a-specific-grid)

I have a Windows Phone 7 application needs 10x10 images inside a grid.

And I'd like to have touch event on each of them but I don't what to write 100 if statements.

Someone tell me to use a control wrap this grid 100 images and set a click event on that control. Can someone show me an example or details with code (xml and cs) on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Download WrapPanel form [Silverlight toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) and use it as a Content Presenter in ListBox. [Example](http://www.kotancode.com/2010/12/29/wp7-presenting-listbox-items-inside-a-wrappanel/).